# Effect trying to run before effects initialised

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a problem with my ngrx setup in that an effect is trying to run before the effects are initialised.

My Redux tool looks like this:

[image: Redux tool]

As you can see, my `[Auth] Create Auth` is trying to run before `@ngrx/effects/init`, and so the effect is not running.

How do I ensure the effects are intialised before any effects are executed/subscribed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `OnInitEffects` hook:

> Implement this interface to dispatch a custom action after the effect has been added. You can listen to this action in the rest of the application to execute something after the effect is registered.

```
class UserEffects implements OnInitEffects {
  ngrxOnInitEffects(): Action {
    return { type: '[UserEffects]: Init' };
  }
}
```

[docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle)